# Dynamic base-path in Spring Data REST

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

How do I configure Spring Data REST (SDR) repositories with dynamic base-paths?

As I [asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554938/spring-data-saas-rest-api-with-uri-based-tenant-identifier), I'd like the following URI-space:

```
/api/{tenant}/
/api/{tenant}/people
/api/{tenant}/products
/api/{tenant}/services
...
/api/{tenant}/foo
```

where each repository (people, products, services, ..., foo) is a typical (or as close to typical as possible) Spring Data REST repository, e.g.:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository 
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String email;
}
```

Tenants are added at runtime and each tenant uses the same repository implementations with the tenant information being passed to the repository implicitly.

Is there a "simple" way to do this in Spring Data REST with Spring Boot 1.3?

Today, Spring Data REST rest exposed a static URL space (i.e., base-path), e.g.:

```
/api/people
/api/products
/api/services
...
/api/foo
```

While we can add a `Tenant` entity and repository to this model, and add the model restrictions to each entity, it would be "nicer" if we could convey the tenant information without explicitly coding it into the domain model. So the question is, how can we do that with SDR?

Comment: Does it **have** to follow the `/api/{tenant}/people` format? Assuming that each `Tenant` has a declared entity relationship with `Person`, Spring Data REST should automatically expose the people linked to each tenant, like so: `api/tenant/28317/people`, where 28317 is the id of the tenant.

Comment: Yes; @JWLim, SDR does do the "Right Thing" with respect to entity relationships, but SDR's HAL representation in that model is (essentially) `_links.people.href : .../api/tenant/128317/people` which have many records like: (essentially) `_embedded.tenets.self.href : .../api/people/123` -- you can choose to not export `people` to avoid exposing the ("un-tenanted") `.../api/people/` resource but that complicates the model. The question is: is there a simple, "natural", way to capture the multi-tenant model in SDR...which is presumably a really common use pattern.

Comment: Would it be helpful if there's an option for SDR to expose a specific tenant like this: `{ "email" : "tenant@foo.com", "people" : [ { "email" : "person1@bar.com" } , { ... } ], "_links" : ... }` ? Is that what you want?

Comment: It's not a question of how to expose the tenant but, rather, exposing a way to allow the URL space to be dynamic based on tenant. I'll add a bit more to my question to help clarify.